# Superfish Css/Jquery Menu goes under Flash Content in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, drop-down-menu, superfish, wmode

http://mindfulintegrations.com/signiacapital/index.html

It works fine in FF3 and IE8 using SwfObject2 and wmode=transparent, but for the life of me I can not get the menu to dropdown over the flash content in IE7. Any help would be appreciated.

I've tried playing around with Z-indexes, and to be honest my understanding of them is somewhat low. Perhaps there is a combination of things I could do to fix my issue?

Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="flash/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var flashvars = {};
        var params = {};
        params.wmode = "transparent";
        var attributes = {};
        attributes.id = "homemovie";
        swfobject.embedSWF("flash/home_movie.swf", "homemovie", "1024", "330", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
    </script>
```

Is the script in my index page.

For Z-indexing, this is the CSS for the various DIV's

for the header container

```
#header-container{ position:relative; height:140px; background-color:#FFFFFF; width:100%; z-index:2; }
```

for the navbar

```
#navbar{ position:absolute; left: 300px; top:90px; clear:both; z-index:1; }
```

for the flash element

```
#homemovie{
height:330px
position:absolute;
z-index:-1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its your style sheet for the site:
http://mindfulintegrations.com/signiacapital/css/style.css

The issue is in #header-content which adds a position in IE7 that you don't want:

```
#header-container{
/**position:relative;**/ /**Overwrites superfish fix for IE7, remove and should work.**/ 
 height:140px; 
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
 width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

i've found a pure JS function that fix it in all browsers!

there you go:

```
function fix_flash() {
    // loop through every embed tag on the site
    var embeds = document.getElementsByTagName('embed');
    for (i = 0; i < embeds.length; i++) {
        embed = embeds[i];
        var new_embed;
        // everything but Firefox & Konqueror
        if (embed.outerHTML) {
            var html = embed.outerHTML;
            // replace an existing wmode parameter
            if (html.match(/wmode\s*=\s*('|")[a-zA-Z]+('|")/i))
                new_embed = html.replace(/wmode\s*=\s*('|")window('|")/i, "wmode='transparent'");
            // add a new wmode parameter
            else
                new_embed = html.replace(/<embed\s/i, "<embed wmode='transparent' ");
            // replace the old embed object with the fixed version
            embed.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', new_embed);
            embed.parentNode.removeChild(embed);
        } else {
            // cloneNode is buggy in some versions of Safari & Opera, but works fine in FF
            new_embed = embed.cloneNode(true);
            if (!new_embed.getAttribute('wmode') || new_embed.getAttribute('wmode').toLowerCase() == 'window')
                new_embed.setAttribute('wmode', 'transparent');
            embed.parentNode.replaceChild(new_embed, embed);
        }
    }
    // loop through every object tag on the site
    var objects = document.getElementsByTagName('object');
    for (i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        object = objects[i];
        var new_object;
        // object is an IE specific tag so we can use outerHTML here
        if (object.outerHTML) {
            var html = object.outerHTML;
            // replace an existing wmode parameter
            if (html.match(/<param\s+name\s*=\s*('|")wmode('|")\s+value\s*=\s*('|")[a-zA-Z]+('|")\s*\/?\>/i))
                new_object = html.replace(/<param\s+name\s*=\s*('|")wmode('|")\s+value\s*=\s*('|")window('|")\s*\/?\>/i, "<param name='wmode' value='transparent' />");
            // add a new wmode parameter
            else
                new_object = html.replace(/<\/object\>/i, "<param name='wmode' value='transparent' />\n</object>");
            // loop through each of the param tags
            var children = object.childNodes;
            for (j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
                try {
                    if (children[j] != null) {
                        var theName = children[j].getAttribute('name');
                        if (theName != null && theName.match(/flashvars/i)) {
                            new_object = new_object.replace(/<param\s+name\s*=\s*('|")flashvars('|")\s+value\s*=\s*('|")[^'"]*('|")\s*\/?\>/i, "<param name='flashvars' value='" + children[j].getAttribute('value') + "' />");
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (err) {
                }
            }
            // replace the old embed object with the fixed versiony
            object.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', new_object);
            object.parentNode.removeChild(object);
        }
    }
}
```

now you can just run in when the page loads with jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            fix_flash();    
 }
```

Comment: in my case, i just switched my object tag to using wmode=transparent, which was why I was having the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate on what you've tried with z-indexes?

My first recommendation would be adding a greater z-index to the #header-container div.

Z-indexes in Internet Explorer can be tricky because and element can retain the z-index of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
.sf-menu a, sf-menu a:hover,sf-menu a.sfHover, .sf-menu li, .sf-menu li li {
  z-index:1;
}
```